# Reading a file is skipping lines in C

Tags: c, file-io

I have a file named `todo.txt` and I have a function that will list every line in the file:

```
void list() {
    FILE *todoFile;
    todoFile = fopen("./todo.txt", "r");
    char line[4096];
    int len;

    if (todoFile != NULL) {
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, todoFile)) {
            len = strlen(line);
            if (len && (line[len - 1] != '\n')) {
                printf("%s", line);
            }
            printf("%s", line);
            fclose(todoFile);
        }
    } else {
        printf("ERROR");
    }

}
```

`todo.txt` contents is:

```
* foo! 
* hello 
* FP!
```

but when I use the `list()` function only the first line is printed:

```
* foo!
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call `fgets()` on a closed file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your file *after* you're done with the reading in the while loop.

```
void list() {
    FILE *todoFile;
    todoFile = fopen("./todo.txt", "r");
    char line[4096];

    if (todoFile != NULL) {
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, todoFile)) {
            printf("%s", line);
        }
        fclose(todoFile);
    } else {
        printf("ERROR");
    }
}
```